# special characters iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uilabel

HEllo, 
I want to know how can I display the special characters in UILabel ?  I want to display " % " symbol in UILabel.

```
calcLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d Goal Complete", progressView.progress];
```

I tried

```
calcLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d % Goal Complete", progressView.progress];
```

then it displays some other value with actual value.

Thanks....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
calcLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d %% Goal Complete",
//                                               ^^
                                            progressView.progress];
```

`%` itself is a special character in a format string, so you need to escape it with another `%`.